# Unable to get the image from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, image-uploading

I'm new to php. I have a sample mysql db in that I have a table named testdb with columns id(INT) and image(BLOB). I have uploaded an image into testdb. Uploaded successfully. The following is the php code. The variable $conn contains the connection details. I have a html page which redirects to this php page on submitting.

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES["sample"]["name"];
echo $name . "<br/>";

$tmp_name = $_FILES["sample"]["tmp_name"];
echo $tmp_name . "<br/>";

$size = $_FILES["sample"]["size"];
echo $size . "<br/>";

$contents = file_get_contents($tmp_name);
$htmlen = htmlentities($contents);
$cont = mysql_real_escape_string($contents);

$query = "INSERT INTO testdb(image)
      VALUES ('$cont')";
$dbquery = mysql_query($query, $conn);
if($dbquery){
    echo "successfully inserted";
    }
else{
    echo "could not inserted" . mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

I am trying to get the image with the following code. But it is showing string characters rather than the image. As far as I know this should work fine.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT image, id
    FROM testdb ";
$dbquery=mysql_query($query , $conn);
if(! $dbquery){
    echo "Could not selected the data from database. " . mysql_error();
}
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($dbquery) ){
    $decodeimg = html_entity_decode($row["image"]);
echo "<img src= $decodeimg/><br/> hellow orld <br/>";
}
?>
```

Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: generally recommended not to store images in the db

Comment: standardly if I need an image to relate to something in my database, I only include link to where image lives instead of going through all the extra work to encode and decode the image and it speeds up the mysql query as well.

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.wellho.net/mouth/937_Display-an-image-from-a-MySQL-database-in-a-web-page-via-PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the actual image in your database (which is redundant because it is probably stored on your server too); why don't you just store the PATH to the image as a string, query the string from your db and then append it to the 'src' attribute with php.

Answer (score -1):

I am also got the same error when show the `BLOB image` from DB. I just use the *decoding method* for this problem....

```
$photo=$myrow['image'];    
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $photo ) . '" width="150" height="150" />
```